# Sites web part not visible

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site

I am experimenting with hub sites on Sharepoint Online. Following the instructions [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-sites-web-part-93cbd17b-0bf8-4355-9f32-cc90e0443e6d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US): 
At the point

> In the web part toolbox, use the search box to search for Sites. Then,
>   select the Sites web part.

I don't see this web part. Do I need to enable it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Which type of site are you using? I have done a test in my team site(without enabling some settings) and everything works fine.

Are you using a  modern page? The Sites web part is a modern web part and it will display only in modern pages.

Go to Pages library in modern experience to create a new "Site Page" and check if you can add sites web part.
[image]